# Why does it print only one in a For Loop

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="g"></p>
function input(){
    var name = window.prompt("What's your name?")
    var num = window.prompt("Input a number")
    for (let i=0; i < num; i++) {
        document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";
    }
}
```

why does it print only One (Hi, + Name + !br) in the page it should be how many times the user input in var num= prompt. .

and if I try Document.write in the function it writes it in another page how I resolve this ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";` will make the latter one override the previous data

Comment: change it to `document.getElementById("g").innerHTML += "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";`

Answer (score 1):

Because `document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = "Hi, " + name + "!<br>"`; will make the latter one override the previous data

In order to output as you expected,you need to store the content into a variable and assign it the element when the loop finished

```
function input(){
    var name = window.prompt("What's your name?")
    var num = window.prompt("Input a number")
    let content = ""
    for (let i=0; i < num; i++) {
        content += "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = content;
}
```

Comment: You don't need another variable to do this, simply use `+=` instead of `=` in `document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";` line

Comment: @deaponn Because I just want to make it more clear to read and debug

Comment: Also this method is technically quicker as you're only accessing the DOM once to update the element after the loop completes.

Comment: @deaponn it's *terrible* advice to use `.innerHTML +=` Yes, it works here but not if you do the seemingly equivalent  `el.innerHTML += "<div>"; el.innerHTML += someData; el.innerHTML += "</div>";` (which makes it easier to read the HTML over several lines). The problem is that *each* write to `innerHTML` is not a simple concatenation but will be parsed as DOM string and any incorrect data will be silently "corrected" during the parsing and subsequent DOM generation. So, you end up with `<div></div>someData<div></div>` instead of just wrapping `someData` in a div tag.

Comment: @VLAZ Okay I get it, and you are right. But wouldn't the string be `<div></div>someData</div>`? The parser inserts `<div>` before the final `</div>` on its own?

Comment: @deaponn `</div>` is not valid HTML. It's not closing anything. You'll only get valid HTML at the end. TBH, I'm not sure if you'd get a full `<div></div>` tag from the closing tag, it might just be omitted entirely. Again, point is that the full string as-is so far will be parsed into DOM representation and normalised. So next read of `.innerHTML` will give you "valid" HTML which might not be what you intended to have. You are guaranteed to not have invalid HTML but that's about it.

Comment: Thank you for everyone that helped me , I have solved the problem it would rely on the += that overrides the whole code, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is only printing one because each time the loop continues , `innerhtml` overrides the previous one.
To solve this problem, change your code

From this:

```
<p id="g"></p>
function input(){
    var name = window.prompt("What's your name?")
    var num = window.prompt("Input a number")
    for (let i=0; i < num; i++) {
        document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";
    }
}
```

To this:

```
<p id="g"></p>
function input(){
    var name = window.prompt("What's your name?")
    var num = window.prompt("Input a number")
    for (let i=0; i < num; i++) {
         document.getElementById("g").innerHTML += "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";
    }
}
```

check the snippet for better understanding:

```js
function input() {
  var name = window.prompt("What's your name?")
  var num = window.prompt("Input a number")
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    document.getElementById("g").innerHTML += "Hi, " + name + "!<br>";
  }
}
input();
```

```html
<p id="g"></p>
```